# How to retrieve controls from ribbon ExcelDNA

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, excel-dna

I was wondering how you are able to retrieve controls from the custom RibbonUI defined in the .dna file that ExcelDNA generates?  Currently I am implementing a login workflow one of the buttons is disabled.  Where the user would login and if successful would enable the disabled button.

Comment: I's suggest first checking the documentation for ExcelDNA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office ribbon interface is purely based on callbacks. So you can't actually 'retrieve controls' from the ribbon and set properties on these. You implement state changes by triggering a callback - in this case probably to your `getEnabled` callback.
To trigger the invalidation of the ribbon, so that your callbacks will be evaluated again, you call Invalidate on the ribbon interface that you get when the ribbon is loaded.

Some C# code that implements this might look like this:

```
public class MyRibbon: ExcelRibbon 
{ 
  private static IRibbonUI _ribbonUi; 

  // This ribbon xml can be returned in code, or places in the .dna     file 
  public override string GetCustomUI(string uiName) 
  { 
    return 
    @" 
    <customUI onLoad='Ribbon_Load' 
              xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui'> 
      <ribbon> 
        <tabs> 
          <tab idMso='TabAddIns'> 
            <group id='group1' label='Group1'> 
              <button id='button1' getEnabled='btn_GetEnabled' getLabel='btn_GetLabel' /> 
            </group> 
          </tab> 
        </tabs> 
      </ribbon> 
    </customUI> 
    "; 
  } 
  public void Ribbon_Load(IRibbonUI sender) 
  { 
    _ribbonUi = sender; 
  } 
  public bool btn_GetEnabled(IRibbonControl control) 
  { 
    return true; 
  } 
  public bool btn_GetLabel(IRibbonControl control) 
  { 
    return "My Button"; 
  } 
  public static void Refresh() 
  { 
    if (_ribbonUi != null) { _ribbonUi.Invalidate(); } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is this still valid in y2019?, some sources like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/accessing-the-ribbon-at-run-time?view=vs-2019 shows that it should be somehow possible to access the Ribbon object oriented way.

Comment: And possibly https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a12d3e02-4e19-4a16-aa7c-b866b922adb0/programatically-load-excel-ribbon-using-c-net-40?forum=vsto

Comment: The documentation your point to is for the VSTO wrapper around the COM interfaces, which give you a higher-level OO view of the ribbon. From an Excel-DNA add-in, where the VSTO helpers are not available, you either have to take the approach above, or make your own wrapper helpers, which is not to hard - just make shadow variables for the ribbon state and update as above from the external interface.

Comment: Is there any way how to detect active Ribbon tab or attach a handler for "on tab change/activate" event?